# Filtering data from one file and writing that data to a new file

Tags: c, file, filtering, text-files, file-writing

I'm trying to copy the file(*customers.txt*) to a new file(*filtered_customers.txt*) while filtering the data. Right now my program only reads in all the entires from the *"customers.txt"* file and copies that into the new file. I'm trying to change this so only entries that have "Dublin" in the 1st column **AND** a 1 in the final column are copied to the new file.

I was looking into using the `strcmp()` function to compare the values in the 1st column with the string "Dublin" and also using this method to compare the entires in the final column to "1" but I've never really done any file processing before so I'm completely lost as to where I'd start. Any advice on how to approach this would be much appreciated, thanks

**CODE - COPIES ALL ENTRIES FROM ONE FILE INTO ANOTHER**

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> // For exit()
#include <conio.h> 

int main() 
{ 
    FILE *fptr1;
    FILE *fptr2; 
    char c; 
  
    char* filename = "C:\\Users\\uzair\\Desktop\\Comp-Programming 2\\customers.txt";
    char* filename2 = "C:\\Users\\uzair\\Desktop\\Comp-Programming 2\\filtered_customers.txt";

    // Open customers.txt file for reading 
    fptr1 = fopen(filename, "r"); 
    if (fptr1 == NULL) 
    { 
        printf("Cannot open file %s \n", filename); 
        exit(0); 
    } 
  

    // Open file for writing 
    fptr2 = fopen(filename2, "w"); 
    if (fptr2 == NULL) 
    { 
        printf("Cannot open file %s \n", filename2); 
        exit(0); 
    } 
  
    // Read contents from file 
    c = fgetc(fptr1); 
    while (c != EOF) 
    { 
        fputc(c, fptr2); 
        c = fgetc(fptr1); 
    } 

    printf("\nContents Copied From ---\n%s\nTo\n%s\nSuccessfully :)\n", filename, filename2); 

    fclose(fptr1); 
    fclose(fptr2); 
    return 0; 
}
```

**customers.txt**

```
Dublin  Dunne       865463389   21  1
Dublin  Milford     865438990   22  0
Dublin  Mowlds      876765443   24  1
Dublin  Wang        873456789   22  1
Dublin  Smith       875432234   25  1
Dublin  Henry       876654429   22  0
Dublin  Gupta       896765443   24  1
Wicklow Monahan     865432245   22  1
Wicklow Brunsdon    865678894   22  1
Wexford Tyson       865434566   22  0
Wexford Browne      865564766   20  1
Dublin  Dunne       890065443   27  1
Dublin  Connolly    876733999   20  0
Louth   Jennings    987645673   60  1
Mayo    Wang        876232123   29  1
```

Comment: break your work into simpler problems. practice the line analysis with fixed data, don't bother with the file until you have that worked out. So, declare a string with sample data in it and work out the filter conditions on that first. As a separate problem, figure out how to get lines of data from your file input stream.

Comment: `printf("Cannot open file %s \n", filename2); exit(0);` seems wrong for a few reasons.  Failure to open a file is generally considered to be an error, so the message should be considered an error message.  But error messages should be written to stderr.  And the message should include the reason the file was not able to be opened. Since there was an error, I would expect the program to fail. IOW, this should be written `perror(filename2); exit(1);`

Comment: Do you know that if you use `stdin` and `stdout` you not only can specify the input and output files in the command line with redirection operands, and you can save all the opening and error detection of the file names you are hardwiring in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *just* copying out the file char-by-char.

The input is a series of lines with separate columns.

We have to accept/reject a line based on matches to the columns.

So, first, we want to read/examine an entire line at once. So, instead of `fgetc`, we want `fgets`

Then, we need to split the line into its columns. There are various ways to do that but the simplest is to make a *copy* of the line. Split up that copy using `strtok`.

Then, the first column can be compared against `Dublin` and the last can be compared against `1`.

If both match, we can output the the [original] line with `fputs`

---

Here's your code refactored to do that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>                     // For exit()
#include <string.h>
//#include <conio.h>

#define BUFMAX      1000

int
is_valid(const char *src)
{
    char *cp;
    char buf[BUFMAX];
    int tokcnt = 0;
    char *toklist[20];
    int match;

    // make a copy of the line (because strtok is destructive of the buffer)
    strcpy(buf,src);

    // split line into tokens/columns keeping track of the number of columns
    while (1) {
        cp = strtok((tokcnt == 0) ? buf : NULL," \t\n");
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;
        toklist[tokcnt++] = cp;
    }

    // check for match
    do {
        // first column must be "Dublin"
        match = (strcmp(toklist[0],"Dublin") == 0);
        if (! match)
            break;

        // last column must be "1"
        match = (strcmp(toklist[tokcnt - 1],"1") == 0);
        if (! match)
            break;
    } while (0);

    return match;
}

int
main()
{
    FILE *finp;
    FILE *fout;

    char *filename = "customers.txt";
    char *filename2 = "filtered_customers.txt";

    // Open customers.txt file for reading
    finp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (finp == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file %s \n", filename);
        exit(0);
    }

    // Open file for writing
    fout = fopen(filename2, "w");
    if (fout == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file %s \n", filename2);
        exit(0);
    }

    // Read contents from file
    char buf[BUFMAX];
    while (1) {
        // read line
        char *cp = fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),finp);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        // output the line if it matches our criteria
        if (is_valid(buf))
            fputs(buf,fout);
    }

    printf("\nContents Copied From ---\n%s\nTo\n%s\nSuccessfully :)\n",
        filename, filename2);

    fclose(finp);
    fclose(fout);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solution, it definitely makes a lot more sense to me now when you go through it like that, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ideas.  Note that this will utterly fail if the whitespace before the final column is a tab instead of a space, and it doesn't verify that there are 4 columns in each row.  There are undoubtedly many other edge cases it misses.  Exercise left for the reader:

```
/* A limited implementation of awk '$1 == "Dublin" && $NF == 1' */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
FILE * xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode);

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        FILE *fptr1 = xfopen( argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "-", "r");
        FILE *fptr2 = xfopen( argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "-", "w");
        char buf[256];

        while( fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fptr1) != NULL ){
                size_t len = strlen(buf);
                if( buf[len - 1] != '\n' ){
                        fprintf(stderr, "input error: line too long\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                if( strncmp("Dublin", buf, 6) == 0 &&
                        strncmp(buf + len - 3, " 1\n", 3) == 0 ){
                        fwrite(buf, 1, len, fptr2);
                }
        }
        fclose(fptr1);
        fclose(fptr2);
        return 0;
}

FILE *
xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
        FILE *fp = path[0] != '-' || path[1] != '\0' ? fopen(path, mode) :
                *mode == 'r' ? stdin : stdout;
        if( fp == NULL ){
                perror(path);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return fp;
}
```

Comment: Note, this also fails if the first column is `Dublinesque` and does not match if there is any leading whitespace.